# Windows 7 won't boot from GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I intially had Windows XP. Later I got Windows 7 and after that Ubuntu 13.04. Then i thought of getting rid of XP part. So I used the DiskPart utility and deleted that partition. But when i tried to set Windows 7 partition as active , it denied the request. On rebooting, Windows 7 could not load. Here is the boot info. I am quite a newbie and I am pretty sure I have messed up my lappy. Please help !

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7152643/

Comment: Windows only boots from primary partitions, so it will not boot from sda8. You have to have boot files in a primary partition and your XP partition had your Windows 7 boot files as well as XP.

Comment: how do i make win7 partition primary ?

Comment: Only because it is the last logical partition in the extended and you have one more primary available you may be able to convert it sda8 to primary. If your Windows is sda6 or sda7 then you cannot.  This may work: http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into Ubuntu and run this command on a terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should detect all the installed systems in the laptop.
Then, reboot the computer. You can do it from the same terminal:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```